# Android Listview: открытие TextView в EditText в новом окне

Tags: android, listview, java

У нас есть ListView, которое по сути состоит из TextView. Как сделать при нажатии на любой TextView, чтобы он открывался в EditText в новом окне?

Comment: а какие данные нужно передать в EditingActivity?

Answer (score 3):

в обработчике события запускаешь новое активити в которое передаешь данные .... но по моему это как то кривовато ... 
может лучше  по клику вызывать кастомный диалог  с едитом ?

Comment: @gadfil я так и делал, просто когда я вызываю новое активити 
Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditingActivity.class);
здесь у меня и происходит ошибка!
он не хочет передавать... подчеркивает красным

Comment: какая ошибка? случайно не The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<mode>) is undefined ?

Comment: @katso да, вроде она, тебе знакома?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(%ActivityName%.this, EditingActivity.class);

Comment: а свою показать сложнее? ошибка в том, что надо писать виесто this - ClassName.this, что бы передать активити, а не вложенный класс - обработчик события.

Comment: @katso даа, спасибо, все заработало!!

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extra name", "твой текст");
startActivity(intent);

А лучше посмотрите в сторону фрагментов в Android SDK http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Фрагменты является более новой и поддерживаемой версией управлениями лейаутами.